# How to combine GWT+Hibernate+MySQL in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, gwt

Good morning,

For my project, I need to develop a web application, for this my choice was: GWT+Hibernate+MySQL+eclipse Helios, however, I'm not able to configure eclipse with all those tools. Is this combinaison possible? if yes, is there any tutorial for using them together? (I was searching on the internet and I didn't find any appropriate tutorial ) and concretly, how can I use hibernate and make connection with MySQL database? (I created all what I need for GWT and now I don't know exactly how to call hibernate)

Any help is welcome,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to 'call' Hibernate you'll need to configure a SessionFactory using an appropriate datasource and mapping metadata describing the mapping of your domain entities to your database structure.

I suggest that you carefully read the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/) before going any further.

Comment: in this documentation, they are using maven, and I don't want to use it.

Comment: From the documentation: It is not a requirement to use Maven. If you wish to use something else to build this tutorial the layout will remain the same. The only change is that you will need to manually account for all the needed dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is Gilead library to integrate GWT and hibernate. try this http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/

Answer (score 0):

I made a tutorial to help people how to do it. Check it:

http://singularityprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/gwt-2-4-0-hibernate-3-6-10-final/